# Debug National Instruments Measurement Studio (No Symbols Loaded)

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, visual-studio-2013, measurement-studio

I've a problem with a `ScatterGraph` from NI Measurement Studio 2015, see [Background Worker: Make sure that ProgressChanged method has finished before executing RunWorkerCompleted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46340028/7556646).

Now I would like to debug the `ScatterGraph`.

[image]

But I can't find the pdf-files for the following dlls:

- NationalInstruments.UI.WindowsForms.dll
- NationalInstruments.UI.dll
- NationalInstruments.Common.dll

Does National Instruments not provide them? Or where can I find them?

Comment: No, somebody like NI won't supply the PDBs.  They don't have a lot of confidence that you'll be able to fix their bugs, given that you don't have their source code.  The stack trace is already very good, a PDB is not going to make it better.  It is actually liable to make it worse because it might give misleading info, PDBs are only really useful in a Debug build.